# How to move an 8 byte string from the stack into a register?

Tags: assembly, system-calls, cpu-registers, execve

ive got trouble by writing a program in asm. This program should execute `/bin/sh`:

```
section .text
global start
start:
    mov rax, 59
    push 0x68732f2f6e69622f
    mov rdi, rsp
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 0
    syscall
```

(59 is the syscall identifier for `execve()` on x64)
(`0x68732f2f6e69622f` is `/bin//sh` in little-endian)

When I ran this, I got a segmentation fault. So I ran strace to check what was happening:

```
execve("./binsh", ["./binsh"], 0x7ffc3453e170 /* 42 vars */) = 0
execve("/bin", NULL, NULL)              = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xfffffffffffffff3} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

So the `/bin`(4 bytes) was moved successfully in from the stack in the `rdi` register. But where is `//sh`? Can someone help?

Comment: Which assembler are you programming for?  It should have warned you that there is no `push` instruction with an 8 byte immediate and thus your immediate was truncated to fit.

Comment: Confirming what @fuz wrote. There is no push imm64, you need to use a register for this. Kind of confusing that it moved four bytes anyway, because in 64bit mode push/pop moves 8 bytes.